# Force consistent behavior when renaming more than 2 objects?

Tags: interface, object-mode

If I want to name a group of objects, starting with "MyObject.000, MyObject.001", etc. there is no reliable way to do this.

Workflow issues:

- The first time I copy/paste the name "MyObject" or "MyObject.000" the source object  gets renamed to "MyObject.001" and the second object becomes "MyObject" or "MyObject.000" respectively.
- Now I cannot rename the first object with the same convention.
- The second time I copy/paste the third object becomes "MyObject.002". Now my objects are ordered { MyObject.001, MyObject.000, MyObject002 }
- Still cannot rename first object with proper increment through copy/paste or keyboard input..?

Is there anyway to force renaming to act consistently regardless of the auto-increment being greater than 1?

Edit: 
I just read there was a batch-rename tool added, but I have no idea how to find it in the interface.
https://developer.blender.org/rBa5b1231de790e4cbf0d4dd62e30afcbc5d8a95f5

Ok. Batch rename is more of a search and replace function. It doesn't have any tools for auto-increment names. You're limited to the .### suffix.

Edit: 
It seems that @ArthurBlaquart is correct, the easiest way to do what I want is with a script.

I found an addon that does what I want and is more efficient than copy/pasting a bunch of times. But, it's from a discussion in a developer thread. 
https://developer.blender.org/T63024#706511

Comment: Your post is a bit confusing, but yes batch renaming is coming for 2.81 (check your version). Right now the best way is to rename multiple objects is with python scripts. I don't see where you found something inconsistent though, I just tried to do what you wrote and found nothing weird in Blender's behavior when handling duplicate names.

Comment: Currently on 2.81 Alpha, Oct. 1, from builder.blender.org. The first time I copy/paste an object name, the object I am copying from gets renamed, as well as the object I am copying to. This does not happen with subsequent copy/paste events.

Comment: Yes but that's only because blender doesn't allow for 2 identical object name. That's why it renames your source object to .001

Comment: Then why does it only happen the first time? On other copy/pastes only the object I am pasting to gets renamed and its value is incremented automatically. It's a different behavior the second time I perform the same action.

Comment: It's the same behavior, it's pretty straigthforward. Names get incremented on duplication or if you try to rename an object with the same name than another one. That's it

Comment: If I copy a name field, and paste it into another name field, 2 objects are renamed. I would expect only the object I am renaming to get renamed. The behavior changes when I paste a second time. Then, only the object I am renaming is changed. The first object keeps it's name. The confusion comes from the first time I paste. Why doesn't the source object keep it's name?